# Получение индекса выбранной RadioButton

Tags: java, android

Есть следующая разметка:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="МАТРИЦА ВЫБОРА ПРОФЕССИИ"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/test1text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_below="@id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="СФЕРА ТРУДА"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Человек"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Информация"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Финансы"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Техника" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Искусство"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Животные"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Растения"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Продукты питания"
                />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Изделия"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Природные ресурсы"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ВИД ТРУДА"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/rg1"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text4"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Управление"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Обслуживание"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Образование"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Оздоровление"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Творчество"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Производство"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Конструирование"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Исследование питания"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Защита"/>

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/RadioButton"
                android:text="Контроль"/>
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/bt2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rg2"
            android:text="РЕЗУЛЬТАТ"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bt2"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

И код:

```
//... 
static int x, y = -1;
//...
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                y = checkedId;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(y), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);
        radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                x = checkedId;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
}
```

Вот только во втором случае (RadioGroup2), при показе ID выбранного элемента он учитывает предыдущую радиогруппу, и выдает число из диапазона [11;20], вместо требуемых [1;10]. В чем ошибка?

Comment: уберите `static` у переменных. Она не меняет свое значение

Comment: в каком месте тут получение значения из БД и какая с этим связана проблема?

Comment: Flippy, это проблему не решило. Вторая RadioGroup все так же показывает индексы от 11 до 20. Я предполагаю, что оно считает обе РГ за одну целую РГ. Но как тогда это исправить?